# How to use the index.html I've designed as the home page of a Wordpress website?

Tags: html, wordpress, templates, indexing

I am designing a portfolio site for a client. I am using Semplice template for Wordpress as it is supposed to be a good theme, but the thing is that is not so customizable as I would like, so I've designed the home page with HTML, CSS and JS on my own, with no templates. So I want to use the index.html I've created only for the home page, and Wordpress+Semplices for the rest of the sections of the website.

Now, I've already uploaded the Wordpress content and database to the host, and it's working. I am uploading my HTML+CSS+JS through the CPanel, but I here comes the problem:

I can upload my files to the root directory of the Wordpress in the public_html folder. If I do it, It keeps using the index.php (which charges the wordpress index, that I don't want), unless I delete this file and leave only the index.html that I've designed, in which case it runs my index but it doesn't loads the rest of the Wordpress even if I write the links to the sections properly. So it looks like this default index.php charges the rest of my wordpress them, and if I delete it, it won'g load anymore.

So, to conclude, I need something that charges both of them, the index.php which will load the rest of the wordpress sections (work, about me, info, etc.) but that uses my index.html as the default home that appears when I write the URL in the browser.

I will show you the files of my public_html folder, just in case it can clarify something for you to help me and understand me better:

[image: a busy cat]

By the way, as you can see in the image, I have no .htaccess file in my folder. That's confusing. What's the reason?

Comment: Files starting with . are hidden files, you have to enable the option to see hidden files in the file manager of cpanel to see the .htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .htaccess file can be not visible, try unhiding it in your File Manager -> Settings -> Show hidden files. If it's still not there, you can create .htaccess file yourself.

After that, it should be an easy redirection with the .htaccess file as this:

RewriteRule ^$ http://example.com/path-to-html.html [L,R=301]

Comment: But yeah, for WordPress to run normally, .htaccess should contain the following code from here too: https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess

Comment: Yeah but editing the .htaccess would be enough to get what I am looking forward to do? I mean, using my index.html as the homepage but allowing the index.php to run to so the rest of the wordpress works as well.

Comment: Yes, if your .html file has the links to the rest of WordPress, it will work just fine. There are some other ways that should help you out, you can check it out here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/296592/how-to-use-custom-html-file-instead-of-wordpress-homepage